# Python: How to return a list of distinct items with counts from a list of lists that includes duplicates?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, nested-lists

I have lists nested within a list. This is the code I have tried with a mini preview of the list to draw up the count of individual nested lists:

```
count_list = [['a', 'b'],['d', 'e'], ['e'], ['c'], ['a', 'b'], ['c']]
    distinct_list = []
    count_list.sort()
    for x in count_list:
        if x not in distinct_list: 
            distinct_list.append(x)       
    for z in distinct_list:
        for y in count_list:
            if y == z:
                print(z, count_list.count(z))
```

I am trying to get the output to be a dictionary / list with only the distinct nested lists and their count so that I can sort the results by count. Lists don't take two values so I am thinking of making it a dictionary for easier storage.
These are the results I get from the above code.

```
(['a', 'b'], 2)
(['a', 'b'], 2)
(['c'], 2)
(['c'], 2)
(['d', 'e'], 1)
(['e'], 1)
```

I want the output to provide only one line for each distinct list and its respective count (rather than multiple lines for the same list as seen in the current output above). Any ideas?

Comment: Your output items look like tuples, do you specifically want a dict instead or you just need some way to group your lists and the counts (so tuples or other types would work fine)?

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to group the lists. I wouldn't mind another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the results as a dict (inline with one of your initial ideas on how to tackle this) would also be fairly simple if you are ok with converting your nested lists to tuples so they can be used as keys. For example:

```
data = [['a', 'b'],['d', 'e'], ['e'], ['c'], ['a', 'b'], ['c']]

results = {}
for d in data:
    t = tuple(d)
    if t not in results:
        results[t] = data.count(d)

print(results)

# OUTPUT
# {('a', 'b'): 2, ('d', 'e'): 1, ('e',): 1, ('c',): 2}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections#collections.Counter):

```
>>> count_list = [['a', 'b'],['d', 'e'], ['e'], ['c'], ['a', 'b'], ['c']]
>>> import collections
>>> result = collections.Counter(tuple(x) for x in count_list)
>>> print(result)
Counter({
    ('c',): 2,
    ('a', 'b'): 2,
    ('d', 'e'): 1,
    ('e',): 1
})
```

Comment: This necessarily has hashable keys (not lists).

Comment: @Alex yup! no problem, just convert whatever to hashable

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use any libraries, even though `Counter` is native to python, you can do...

```
arr = [[1, 2], [3], [1, 2], [4], [3]]
new_arr = []
for elem in arr:
    # You are wrapping your element in a list, at the same scale
    # than the list you wish to output (meaning 3 dimensions depth list).
    # In other words, you have a list... that contains a list, containing
    # your element and its count. The first depth seems useless at first glance,
    # but it's just here to keep the same depth you will have appending to new_arr.

    # You can try by yourself doing "obj = [elem, arr.count(elem)]" if you don't
    # believe me.
    obj = [ [elem, arr.count(elem)] ]
    if obj[0] not in new_arr:
        # checking on first index to check our elem and not our ""wrapper""
        new_arr += obj

print(new_arr)
# [[[1, 2], 2], [[3], 2], [[4], 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you convert to *tuples* you can use *dictionary comprehension*

```
count_list = [tuple(i) for i in count_list]

d = {i: count_list.count(i) for i in set(count_list)}
```

> ```
> {('a', 'b'): 2, ('d', 'e'): 1, ('c',): 2, ('e',): 1}
> ```